# Is there any public data to get OIS for differal time (1d, 1W, 1M, ..., 10Y)?

Tags: black-scholes, market-data, quants, risk-free, ois

I want to get data of Overnight Index Swap, also known as OIS rate, there is any public why to get this always from yesterday?

For example, I want to get EFFR(Effective Federal Funds Rate), I can get here:
https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/EFFR

Some one give a light of how to solve my problem. I am trying to solve price for FX Option, what I did, I just have to adjust the OIS rate for differal time and I done my job.

Comment: Pretty sure market provide it for free via an api - you get a zipped xml if I recall correctly.

Comment: I am looking for it, but I am really inexperient about the data. I didn't find yet;

Comment: Really would like a help here or a direction. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So you can get depo and swap rates from markit daily, at links like this:

```
http://www.markit.com/news/InterestRates_<cncy>_<yyyymmdd>.zip
```

i.e.

http://www.markit.com/news/InterestRates_USD_20170105.zip

and there's a spec for it [here](http://www.cdsmodel.com/cdsmodel/assets/cds-model/docs/Interest%20Rate%20XML%20v1.3.pdf) - though that's from 2009 so may be out of date, maybe you can find a more up to date one someone on their site, but i've noot been able to inside of a few minutes of googling.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't up you because I don't have pontuation. I will look the site, but thank you man

Comment: @FilipeCotrimMelo don't worry about it.

Answer (score 2):

CME (as of now) also publishes it.

Folder: ftp://ftp.cmegroup.com/irs/

file name: irs_close_quotes_OISUSD_YYYYMMDD.csv, e.g. 20200717

```
CURVE_NAME,TENOR,RATE
USD LIBOR-OIS DISCOUNT CURVE,2 Years,0.0033500000
USD LIBOR-OIS DISCOUNT CURVE,3 Years,0.2200000000
USD LIBOR-OIS DISCOUNT CURVE,5 Years,0.2212830000
USD LIBOR-OIS DISCOUNT CURVE,10 Years,0.2172810000
USD LIBOR-OIS DISCOUNT CURVE,30 Years,0.1971580000
```

there are many other curves for other currencies in this folder.

Answer (score 0):

Go to this site and download the application that contains OIS curves for all major currencies at https://finpricing.com/download.html[image: OIS and Swap curves]

Comment: Thus requires signing up for the service using your email address (which I prefer not to give out).